# How do you use MaskedEditExtender for both letters and numbers?

Tags: asp.net, maskededitextender

I've got the following line of code:

```
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeLegID" runat="server" MaskType="None" Mask="LLLLL" 
TargetControlID="txtLegID" PromptCharacter="_"  InputDirection="LeftToRight" 
AutoComplete="False" />
```

The problem is, it only accepts letters.  If I set the **Mask="99999"**, it only accepts numbers.  So what do you set Mask to in order for it to accept *both* letters and numbers?

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer.

```
Mask = "?????"
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Is there something incomplete about this answer?